# Globally set dynamic pug variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am using express and pug, there are some values that I would like to pass to pug on every request, for example: `req.session` and `req.path`. Passing these values to the `render()` method every time just seems too redundant.

So instead of doing something like this:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home', {session: req.session})
})
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    res.render('profile', {session: req.session})
})
```

The more routes that get added, the more of those items I need to manage. Is there a global way that I can set them once other than `app.locals` so they are unique per request?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set variables that are available to every template on each request using a bit of custom middleware and [`locals`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.locals). This same approach works for all templating systems that Express can use, not just Pug.

Put the following *before* your routes.

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.locals.session = req.session
  next()
})
```

Then in your template you can call it like this.

```
h3= session.name
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for!